# How to use DatePickerDialog in BaseAdapter

Tags: android, baseadapter, datepickerdialog

I am working with the `BaseAdapter` Class. I want to Display `DatePickerDialog` in it.
When I use `showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);`  I am getting error.

Please guide me regarding this.

package com.OrganisemeePhone.adapter;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.OpenableColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;




public class TaskFilterAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String date, month, year,setdueDate;
    //int dateFormat;
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener;

    int myYear, myMonth, myDay;
    int dateFormat;
    int starcount=0;

    public TaskFilterAdapter datedialog;

    viewholder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflator;
    ArrayList<Integer> taskId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<String> task = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> dueDate = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> priority = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    Vector<Boolean> VectorCheckChange = new  Vector<Boolean>(); 
    Vector<Object> taskrow = new Vector<Object>();  

    static int pos;
    Context context;
    private boolean isdaymonth;
    public TaskFilterAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Integer> taskId, ArrayList<String> task, ArrayList<Integer> priority, ArrayList<String> duedate) {
        super();

        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.taskId = taskId;
        this.context=context;

        this.task = task;
        this.dueDate = duedate;
        this.priority = priority;

        //dateFormat=LoginActivity.db.getdateformat();
        getDateFormate();
        dateFormat=LoginActivity.db.getdateformat();
        getDateFormate();
        for(int i=0; i<task.size(); i++)
        {
            VectorCheckChange.add(false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return task.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            holder = new  viewholder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.task_row, null);
            holder.task = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_text);
            holder.date = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_date_text);
            holder.star = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_star);
            holder.chk = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_row_check_box);

            holder.task.setOnClickListener(new Clicker());
            holder.chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new Checker());
            holder.star.setOnClickListener(new Clicker());
            holder.date.setOnClickListener(new Clicker());

            setviewAsSettings();

            setviewAsSettings();


            convertView.setTag(holder);


            }
        else
        {
            holder=(viewholder)convertView.getTag();
        }


        pos = position;

        /****************** Set Task *************************/

        holder.task.setText(task.get(position));
        holder.task.setTag(position);
        holder.star.setTag(position);
        holder.date.setTag(position);



        /***************** Set Duedate ***********************/

        setdueDate = dueDate.get(position);

        month = setdueDate.substring(5, 7);
        date = setdueDate.substring(8, 10);



        if (!date.equals("00"))
        {
            if (isdaymonth) 
            if (isdaymonth)
            {
                holder.date.setText(date + "." + month + ".");
                Log.d("taskList Adapter"," date formate day month ");

            } 
            else 
            {
                holder.date.setText(month + "." + date + ".");
                Log.d("taskList Adapter"," date formate month  day");

            }
        } 
        else
        {
            holder.date.setText("");
        }



        /***************** Set Priority ***********************/


                if (priority.get(position).equals(-1) || priority.get(position).equals(0)|| priority.get(position).equals(3)) 
                {

                    holder.star.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_low));

                } 
                else if (priority.get(position).equals(2)) 
                {

                    holder.star.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_med));
                }
                else if (priority.get(position).equals(1)) 
                {

                    holder.star.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_high));
                }




        /******************* Set tag in checkBox ******************************/

        holder.chk.setTag(position);

        if(VectorCheckChange.get(position))
        {
            holder.chk.setChecked(true);
            holder.task.setPaintFlags(holder.task.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            holder.task.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#848484"));
            holder.date.setPaintFlags(holder.task.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            holder.date.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#848484"));
            holder.task.setClickable(false);
            holder.task.setEnabled(false);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.chk.setChecked(false);
            holder.task.setPaintFlags(holder.task.getPaintFlags() & ~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            holder.task.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            holder.date.setPaintFlags(holder.task.getPaintFlags() & ~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            holder.date.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
            holder.task.setClickable(true);
            holder.task.setEnabled(true);
        }


        return convertView;
    }
    // updates by nilesh
    public void setviewAsSettings(){
        //check for task setting
        SharedPreferences startup_pref = 
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        Boolean viewpriority=startup_pref.getBoolean("viewpriority", true);
        Boolean viewduedate=startup_pref.getBoolean("viewduedate", true);

            if(!viewpriority){
                holder.star.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }               
            if(!viewduedate){
                holder.date.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        //check for task setting completed
    }

    public class viewholder
    {
        TextView task,date;
        ImageView star;
        CheckBox chk;

    }


    public class Clicker implements OnClickListener
    {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            int position=(Integer)v.getTag();
            int setPriority = 0;

        if(v.getId() ==  holder.date.getId())
        {


            Log.i("Date Dialog Picker", "Click Date..................... ");

            ((Activity)context).showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID); 

        //.showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);


            //.showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);



            }
        dateListener =  new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yr, int monthOfYear,
                    int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myYear = yr;
                myMonth = monthOfYear;
                myDay = dayOfMonth;

                }

            };  



        if(v.getId() == holder.task.getId())
        {
            Intent display_int= new Intent(context, DisplyTaskActivity.class);
            display_int.putExtra(constantcode.TASK_ID,taskId.get(position));
            v.getContext().startActivity(display_int);

            Log.i("TaskList Adapter", "Task ....position...... "+holder.star.getTag());
        }


            if(v.getId() == holder.star.getId())
            {

                 if (priority.get(position).equals(-1) || priority.get(position).equals(0) || priority.get(position).equals(3)) 
                   {
                     priority.set(position, 2);
                     setPriority = 2;

                    holder.star.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_low));

                    Log.d("TaskList Adapter", "----- Grey ----");
                   } 
                   else if (priority.get(position).equals(2)) 
                   {
                       priority.set(position, 1);
                       setPriority = 1;

                    holder.star.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_med));

                    Log.d("TaskList Adapter", "----- Yellow ----");
                   }
                   else if (priority.get(position).equals(1)) 
                   {
                       priority.set(position, 0);
                       setPriority = 0;

                    holder.star.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_high));

                    Log.d("TaskList Adapter", "----- Orange ----");
                   }


                  String  updateQuery = "update tbl_tasks set priority =" + setPriority + " where taskId="+ taskId.get(position);
                  LoginActivity.db.execNonQuery(updateQuery);


                   taskrow = LoginActivity.db.getTaskRow(taskId.get(position));

                    if(taskrow.get(2).toString().contains("'"))
                    {
                        taskrow.set(2, taskrow.get(2).toString().replace("'", "''"));
                    }

                    String insertQuery = "insert into tbl_update_tasks(taskId,listId,description,priority,dueDate,reminderId,senderId,receiverId,taskCategoryType,fadeDate,assignedId)values("+ taskrow.get(0) + ","+ taskrow.get(1)+ ",'"+ taskrow.get(2)+ "',"+ taskrow.get(3)+ ",'"+ taskrow.get(4)+ "',"+ taskrow.get(5)+ ","+ taskrow.get(6)+ ","+ taskrow.get(7)+ ",'"+ taskrow.get(8)+ "','"+ taskrow.get(9)+ "',"+ taskrow.get(10)+ ");";
                    LoginActivity.db.execNonQuery(insertQuery);
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

                //Log.w("taskfilterAdapter","position....... "+v.getTag());
        }


    }

      Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
            switch(id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:

                return new DatePickerDialog(this.context, dateListener, myYear, myMonth,myDay);

            }

            return null;

        }

    /* public class datedialogclicker extends Activity
    {


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            holder.date.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Log.v("New Class....", "Click OnClick.....");
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID); 
                }

            });

            dateListener =  new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yr, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    myYear = yr;
                    myMonth = monthOfYear;
                    myDay = dayOfMonth;

                    }

                };  



        }
         protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
                switch(id) {
                case DATE_DIALOG_ID:

                    return new DatePickerDialog(context, dateListener, myYear, myMonth,myDay);

                }

                return null;

            }
    }*/

    public class Checker implements OnCheckedChangeListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int posi=(Integer)buttonView.getTag();

            if(isChecked)
            {
                VectorCheckChange.set(posi, true);              
            }
            else
            {
                VectorCheckChange.set(posi, false);
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

    }
    // update by nilesh
    public void getDateFormate() {

        // Get the app's shared preferences
        SharedPreferences startup_pref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        // Get the value for the run counter
        isdaymonth = startup_pref.getBoolean(constantcode.ISDAYMONTH, true);
    }


}
```

Comment: What kind of error you are getting ?

Comment: @Android are u using date picker in listview???

Comment: I have posted the code please reefer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1)Define this code in BaseAdapter onClick

```
((Activity)AdapterName.this.context).showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
```

(2)below code in Activity:

```
 DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateListener =  new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int yr, int monthOfYear,
                        int dayOfMonth) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    myYear = yr;
                    myMonth = monthOfYear;
                    myDay = dayOfMonth;

                }


         }; 


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        myYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        myMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        myDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
            switch(id) {
            case DATE_DIALOG_ID:

                return new DatePickerDialog(ActivityName.this, dateListener, myYear, myMonth, myDay);

            }
            return null;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is easy to justify: it is not exception it is compilation error - showDialog is a method of Activity class. It is so easy for the Android developers to forget that all these nice auxiliary methods should also be provided by some class right?

So the thing is that `OnClickListener` is not `Activity`. Make constructor of the class accepting single parameter activity, store it in local variable and then call its method showDialog:

```
private Activity activity;
public Clicker(Activity  activity) {
  this.activity = activity;
}

...
  this.activity.showDialog();
...
```

Comment: I try it. now it doesn't give an error, but the datepickerdialog is not show still.

Comment: Well I can see that it's display depends on some conditions. Please make sure these conditions are met and you trigger the onClick event. You the logCat for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the problem of storing value of datepicker in the listview but resolved it.This is the code for it.Hope it helps.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DAteDemo extends Activity{

    private ListView listViewScore = null;
    private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter = null;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    private int mYear;    
    private int mMonth;  
    private int mDay;
    int globalPosition; //used for storing the position of textview clicked for setting the date

    ArrayList<String> mfddateList = null;
    int viewlength = 30;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        listViewScore=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewScore);

        mfddateList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<30;i++){
            mfddateList.add("");
        }

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();        
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);        
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);        
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 

        listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter();
        listViewScore.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);


    }

    class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return viewlength;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ViewHolder viewHolder ;
            View rowView=view;

            if(rowView==null){
                LayoutInflater layoutinflate =LayoutInflater.from(DAteDemo.this);
                rowView=layoutinflate.inflate(R.layout.listviewnewtext, parent, false);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.et_Sort_Order = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.et_Sort_Order);

                //Setting listen to the text box
                viewHolder.et_Sort_Order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                        globalPosition = viewHolder.ref; // this is used to update the date
                        Log.i("Log","date:-- "+viewHolder.ref);
                    }

                });

                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            }

            viewHolder.ref = position;

            viewHolder.et_Sort_Order.setText(mfddateList.get(position));



            return rowView;
        }
    }//class ends

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView et_Sort_Order;
        int ref;
    }

    // the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog    
    public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =            
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {                
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,                                       
                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {                    
            mYear = year;                    
            mMonth = monthOfYear;                    

            String date = (mMonth + 1)+"/"+mYear; 
            mfddateList.set(globalPosition,date);
            Log.i("Log", "i m in dateset "+globalPosition);
            listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //for updating the date change

        }            
    };

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {  
        switch (id) {    
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:        
            return new DatePickerDialog(DAteDemo.this,mDateSetListener,mYear, mMonth,mDay );    
        }    
        return null;
    }

}//ActivityEnds


 **main.xml** 
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listViewScore"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.00"
    android:divider="#C0C0C0"
    android:layout_below="@+id/layout"
    android:dividerHeight="2dip"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

```
**listviewnewtext.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="0dip"
    >

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:id="@+id/et_Sort_Order"

        >

    </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Android Yes...every thing is in Activity class...declared variables are global...getview is in class which is extending baseadapter

Comment: @Android I have editted my above code and posted a demo project code for storing datevalue in listview...I am  also looking at your code and will update if I figure out something...